# .net core web API access variable in controller from other classes

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

In my asp.net core web API, i want to access variable in my controller. The variable will set while GetAllStudents method running. StudentController and StudentRepository is in same solution but different project. How can i access from StudentRepository.cs to variable in StudentController.cs? There is some solution for MVC, but i can't find for web API. So, question is **not duplicate**.

StudentController.cs :

```
 int requestedUserId;

 [HttpGet("GetAllStudents")]
 public async Task<ServiceResult>GetAllStudents()
    {
        requestedUserId= context.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"];
        return await (studentService.GetAllStudents(requestedUserId));
    }
```

StudentService.cs :

```
 public async Task<ServiceResult> GetAllStudents()
    {
        return await unitOfWork.studentRepo.GetAllStudents();
    }
```

StudentRepository.cs :

```
public async Task<List<Student>> GetAllStudents()
    {
        ?????var requestedUserId= StudentController.requestedUserId;?????
        LogOperation(requestedUserId);
        return context.Students.ToList();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. The solution is "IHttpContextAccessor". You can inject by dependency injection and then you can use from everywhere (forexample dbcontext class)

```
public class StudentService : IStudentService
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public StudentService(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

public async Task<List<Student>> GetAllStudents()
    {
        var requestedUserId= _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Headers["Authorization"];
        LogOperation(requestedUserId);
        return context.Students.ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: How is adding `var requestedUserId= _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Headers["Authorization"];` easier than passing the value in?

Comment: Because writing only one time instead of 30.000 times. Forexample, architecture in question, there are 10 method in controller.cs. Then 10 method in service.cs which is called from controller. Then 40 methods in repository.cs which called from service. If i write like you, i must add parameter UserId said for every method (60 times). @tymtam

Comment: But if use IHttpContextAccessor, I write repository.cs only one time. And then call it if i need. If you want also, you can do global by writing DbContext on overrided saveChanges method. And for every database operation it automatically trigger. So, by your solution, if i have 30.000 method in my application, then i must write more than 30.000 row code. But in "IHttpContextAccessor" solution you will write only 4 row code. It is easily understandable that 4 much more smaller and easier than 30000. @tymtam

Answer (score 1):

You can just pass it in.

`GetAllStudents(int userId)`

---

Update:

*Re: Thanks for your reply. But this variable is used every method in every controller. So i don't want write everywhere (int userId).*

You should pass it to every method that needs it:

1. It's a common pattern
2. Methods don't depend on a controller
3. Passing it is actually less code than: `var requestedUserId= StudentController.requestedUserId;?????`

Comment: And it's probably worth noting that it doesn't make sense it being a class-scoped variable.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But this variable is used every method in every controller. So i don't want write everywhere (int userId). I ask this question for this reason @John

Comment: @Hasan but the API calls are stateless, so in each API method you're assigning it `requestedUserId= context.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"];`. Are you asking how to avoid that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52352498/where-can-be-stored-user-info-in-net-core-api-project-with-angular. I ask my original question in this post. But i can't find answer. So i think this solution like class variable. Is there any way of do this? Because my main purpose is taking a LOG for every database operration. Can you reply my other post please?  @John

Comment: The point is that the controller is instantiated and disposed *with each request*. In other words, setting an ivar or something is pointless, because the next request will have an entirely different instance of this controller without that ivar set.

Comment: @HasanOzdemir are you looking for `User.Identity.Name`? Anyway, whereever you decide to store the id of the user the repo methods should have it passed in. This is the standard way to do it and it keeps things separated.

Comment: @John My project has more than 5000 action. And sending in every method is very big mistake. I found the solution. "HttpContextAccessor" is what i was looking for. So, i will write only one time instead of in 5.000 time.

Comment: @HasanOzdemir It's absolutely amazing that a product you're working on manged to ignore authentication until it has 5000 operations!

Comment: @HasanOzdemir If your requirement is to log user details for database operations, you should use log context. It is easier to write a middleware for pushing custom properties(user details) into log context and log them wherever required.

Comment: Thanks @SivaChamarthi. Your solution is also can solve my problem. But, I used IHttpContextAccessor and it solved the problem.

Comment: @tymtam 
you never understood my question. Please  read the question again before discussion.

Comment: No I'm sorry mate, but it seems you never took time to understand the answer :)