# What is the best way of pass user info in request header to repository class in .net core Api

Tags: angular, entity-framework, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an .net Core Web API angular project. I send JWT in every request. My purpose is log every database operation. I can take UserInfo from controller request header. But i should take UserInfo from DbContext. Because of creating auto log at DbContext class. But i cannot access. 
   I think that solution as, create global action filter for all action. And in action filter when action start, set Session to UserInfo. And DbContext take UserInfo from Session. And when action finished, remove session. But I think, this is very bad solution. Because, creating session for every request. What is the best way for logging database operation for .net Core web API?

```
public class LogAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        Session["UserInfo"] = null;      
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        Session["UserInfo"] = HttpContext.RequestHeader["Authorization"];
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you authenticating the user? Are you using the built in .net core identity?

Comment: No. My authentication is custom from database and i am using Jwt. It is not .net core identity. @JamieRees

Comment: @HasanOzdemir shouldn't JWT already include user info in its payload? example: https://jwt.io/#debugger

Comment: @woodykiddy My UserInfo is in Jwt. And i send it also. I can easily access jwt from controller. But the problem is, can't access from DbContext class.

Comment: I don't understand why you're trying to take a value out of the `HttpContext` and store it elsewhere between `OnActionExecuting`  and `OnActionExecuted`. You should just be able to use `HttpContext.RequestHeader["Authorization"]` anywhere you would use `Session` in this example. I'd like to see more about *how and where* you use `Session` with this approach as it stands.

Comment: @KirkLarkin My detailed problem is in my this post. Please can you control this post? The problem is, in .net core, i can access RequestHeader only from controller class. I can't access from other class.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52352498/where-can-be-stored-user-info-in-net-core-api-project-with-angular

Comment: In which case, it might be better to update your existing question and delete this one.

Comment: I wait for that question but any people didn't answer that question. So i am forced to new post. I will delete that post.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [where can be stored user info in .net core API project with angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52352498/where-can-be-stored-user-info-in-net-core-api-project-with-angular)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DbContext` has an internal service provider. You'll need to add two things to your `Startup.cs`:

```
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

services.AddDbContext(o => o
    .UseSqlServer(...) // or whatever
    .UseInternalServiceProvder());
```

Then, you can override something like `SaveChangesAsync` to do your logging. To access the user:

```
var httpContextAccessor = GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>();
var principal = httpContextAccessor?.HttpContext.User;
```

Be aware that since a `DbContext` can be used outside of a request, `httpContextAccessor` could be null. That's why the null conditional operator is used above. That however, means that `principal` could be null, as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot. HttpContextAccessor is what i was looking for. It worked.